# ngRepeat number of items in an array that has been orderedBy

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sorting

I'm working on a portfolio website where on the index, it should only display the five latest items added to the portfolio. Seeing as I'm relatively new to AngularJS and its ordering features, I am struggling. Currently, I can do this:

```
 <div class="media z-depth-1" ng-repeat="pub in pubs | limitTo:quantity | orderBy: '-date'" style="padding:20px">
```

`limitTo`of course is set to 5. Now, this conflicts with `orderedBy` which will display the articles sorted by a value in the array that is a date. I did this so that the items do not have to be entered in chronological sequence, which makes building a backlog much easier and comfortable.

However, with this, it will only show me the first five entries in the array, which are not sorted. So how do I get it to first sort the array and then take the first five sorted items so that I get the five latest items on the index page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the order of the filters so that you orderby first, then limit.